# Override default icon of primefaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am new to primefaces, I want to override or change the default icon `ui-icon-circle-triangle-e` of rowtoggler to `ui-icon-plus`. Please tell me if it is possible, and if so how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either drop all Primefaces styles using the following code in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

or if you like the overall styling simply override the class responsible for this particular icon, which is `.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e`

You can then add a new css selector to a file that comes after theme.css or is more specific. Specificity is the better way to go. Add a `styleClass="plus-table"` on the `<p:dataTable>` and a css selector/style like

```
.plus-table .ui-icon-circle-triangle-e {
    background-position: -16px -128px;
}
```

the same for minus:

```
.plus-table .ui-icon-circle-triangle-s {
    background-position: -48px -128px;
}
```

should work. You can always add the `.plus-table` to a template element so it applies everywhere and you don't need to add it to each component

**See also**:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles?rq=1)